# How to show child data of a userid of firebase data in my recyclerview?

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show this snapchat and twitter in my recycler view

[image]

```
 String userid=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
 db=db.child(userid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
String currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(currentUser);    
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                                      
         String snap_user = dataSnapshot.child("Snapchat").child("username").toString();
         String twiter_user = dataSnapshot.child("twiter").child("username").toString();                    
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // Don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: i got it but i need my recyclerview to show me only  childs of a user id i.e(snapchat and twitter ) in this case  if user contain more childs  other then snapchat and twitter recyclerview displays them

Comment: yes i  want to show childs of current user i.e snapchat and twitter if they exist